# Saving a file on internal storage in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, save

I am trying to save a parsed XML from web to a local storage.
I am using the following code (**this code is in HandleXML.java**):

**CODE**

```
public void fetchXML(){
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(urlString);
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
                        url.openConnection();
                        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.connect();
                        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                        XMLdata =String.valueOf(stream);

                        //createFile(XMLdata);
                        String filename = "XMLdata";
                        FileOutputStream outputStream;
                        try {
                             outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                             outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
                             outputStream.close();
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                              }

                        xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                        XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                        myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES
                                , false);
                        myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                        parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();


        }
```

**ERROR:**  Cannot resolve method openFileOutput.

If I try to fix the error with suggested fix, it creates me a method, but still it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

I think the reason is because I dont use it in MainActivity. If so, can you suggest me a fix? Because I fetch the XML inside HandleXML class.

Comment: Why don't you pass the activity into the method?

Comment: How would that look, if you don't mind telling me?

Comment: I'm not sure how to express it any clearer than that...

Comment: `getApplicationContext.openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVAT);`

this doesnt work if you meant this

Comment: That's not what I meant. Add the activity as an argument to the method. You then have the activity to call `openFileInput` in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void fetchXml(Activity a) {
    a.openFileInput(...);
}
```